# Saving Core Data on seperate thread with Magic Record

Tags: ios, objective-c, magicalrecord

I am using Magical Record to help with core data saving and multi threading.

I kick off a new thread with GCD. In that new thread, I check if an Entity exists; if it does not I want to create a new one and save it.

Will `saveUsingCurrentThreadContextWithBlock^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext){}` return to the main thread to save if it is called on a non-main thread?

or should i just pass the context to the new thread?

EDIT:

On the main thread, I create a MBProgress indicator and create a new thread:

```
MBProgressHUD *HUD = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.mapView animated:YES];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{

    Person *person = [Person MR_findFirstByAttribute:NAME withValue:self.user.username];

    if (person == NULL) {
        NSLog(@"SEPERATE THREAD | person %@ does not exist, creating", self.user.username);
        person = [Person MR_createEntity];
        person.name = self.user.username;
        person.uid = self.user.UID;

        [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread] MR_saveOnlySelfWithCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
            [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.mapView animated:YES];

            Person *person = [Person MR_findFirstByAttribute:NAME withValue:self.user.username];

            if (person) {
                NSLog(@"COMPLETION BLOCK | person exists: %@", person.name);
            }
        }];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"SEPERATE THREAD | person %@ does", self.user.username);

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.mapView animated:YES];
            });
    }
});
```

(this method of saving is not persistence, I restart the app and I can't find the Person entity):

```
2013-03-12 14:25:44.014  SEPERATE THREAD | person iDealer does not exist, creating
2013-03-12 14:25:44.014  SEPERATE THREAD | thread: <NSThread: 0x84ca720>{name = (null), num = 4}
2013-03-12 14:25:44.015  -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x840ec30) → Saving <NSManagedObjectContext (0x840ec30): *** UNNAMED ***> on *** BACKGROUND THREAD ***
2013-03-12 14:25:44.015  -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x840ec30) → Save Parents? 0
2013-03-12 14:25:44.015  -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x840ec30) → Save Synchronously? 0
2013-03-12 14:25:44.016  -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalRecord) MR_contextWillSave:](0x840ec30) Context UNNAMED is about to save. Obtaining permanent IDs for new 1 inserted objects
2013-03-12 14:25:44.132  __70-[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:]_block_invoke21(0x840ec30) → Finished saving: <NSManagedObjectContext (0x840ec30): *** UNNAMED ***> on *** BACKGROUND THREAD ***
2013-03-12 14:25:44.134  COMPLETION BLOCK | thread: <NSThread: 0x8435f30>{name = (null), num = 1}
2013-03-12 14:25:44.134  COMPLETION BLOCK | person exists: iDealer
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I got it to work:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    Person *person = [Person MR_findFirstByAttribute:NAME withValue:self.user.username];

    if (person == NULL) {
            [MagicalRecord saveUsingCurrentThreadContextWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext){
                Person *localPerson = [Person MR_createInContext:localContext];
                localPerson.name = self.user.username;

            } completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error){
                [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.mapView animated:YES];
            }];
    }
    else {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.mapView animated:YES];
        });
    }
});
```

This works and save. I am unsure what casademora means by this method is incorrect. I am not able to determine what the difference between using this method to using `saveOnlySelf:completion:` method.

It seems like I was never able to save the context to the persistent store with the `saveOnlySelf`. If I created it with the code in my question, it would get placed in the context. If I did a search for the Person entity, I could find it. But once I terminated the app and restarted, that Person entity would not be there. It felt like I was saving or merging the thread context to the main/default context but that context was not being saved.

EDIT:

After some more playing around with MR, it seems that if any of the `saveOnlySelf` methods are used in a non-main thread, it will merge local context to the default context, but it does not save it to the persistent store. If you check the default context after completion, the new entity is indeed there. But once you terminate the app and re-run it, it isn't there.

To merge the context and save to the store, you need to call one of the `saveToPersistentStoreAndWait` type methods.

Comment: The code inside 'saveUsingCurrentThreadContextWithBlock' is being executed in a background thread (as per MR docs) - why exactly do you use GCD here ?

Answer (score 2):

In the current version of MagicalRecord, yes, the completion block will return to the main thread. However, your method here is incorrect. There are now more explicit variants of the save method:

```
saveOnlySelf:completion:
saveToPersistentStore:completion:
```

Have a look at these methods in the current version. And as a reminder, make sure you only use managed objects from the localContext given to you. That working block can be run in any thread/queue, and you still want to use the proper thread management rules for core data in this case.

Comment: Er, does this only save it to the main context? Does it save the main context or do I still need to do that manually?

Comment: there are two ways the default context is saved here: 1) the child context is a child of the default context, 2) the child context is a distant child of the default context, and saveToPersistentStore:completion: is called.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the completion block with execute in the main thread. For example:

```
NSOperationQueue *newQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[newQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{
    [MagicalRecord saveUsingCurrentThreadContextWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
        // save something
    } completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
        // this will execute in the main thread
    }];
}];
```